# How can I fix Ceph error while ceph-deploy

Tags: ceph

I am set up a ceph cluster right now and  would like to create a cluster.

I've never set up ceph before, but when execute `ceph-deploy` on user with `root` rights, not root on `/` there is no error. After that I read in the manual to set it up in an folder and an user account so I've removed ceph and the keys and started again.

```
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_deploy/util/decorators.py", line 69, in newfunc
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]     return f(*a, **kw)
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_deploy/cli.py", line 147, in _main
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]     fh = logging.FileHandler('ceph-deploy-{cluster}.log'.format(cluster=args.cluster))
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 902, in __init__
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in _open
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/cluster/ceph-deploy-ceph.log'
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below command

(chown ceph:ceph /home/myuser/cluster)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/cluster/ceph-deploy-ceph.log'

Answer (score 0):

Its Seems you using user named "myuser" and running the command using root rights. So ceph will asume you as a root user. `ceph-deploy` would create a deploy log file in current directories. Maybe you run this first ceph-deploy command using root rights, then you run the second `ceph-deploy` command using a "myuser" user. I think thats the problem. You should change permissions on ~/cluster/ceph-deploy.log file to be write/read on "myuser" user.

Change your directory permissions to "myuser" with `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser/cluster`

And if you want to restart deploying cluster, please remove all file in yout ~/cluster directories. Then purge ceph packages and purge all data in /var/lib/ceph/ using `ceph-deploy purge <node>` and `ceph-deploy purgedata <node>`. Also using `ceph-deploy forgetkeys` command to remove keys.

Answer (score 0):

As root on the server:

```
mkdir /home/myuser/cluster/
chown myser. -R /home/myuser/cluster/
```

And run `ceph-deploy` again as `myuser`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind, you can also just remove the log and try running the command again.

```
sudo rm /home/myuser/cluster/ceph-deploy-ceph.log
```